# No difference in meaning between "do calculations" and "make calculations"

Tags: difference

Do "do calculations" and " make calculations' mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The term "make calculations" is not something that a native US English speaker would say.  It also doesn't really make sense since calculations are not something that you "make" but rather something you do.

"In order to solve this problem you will be required to do calculations."

Even better, in my opinion, is the word "perform" here.

"In order to solve this problem you will be required to perform calculations."